# swift passing data from a tableview cell to view controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I'm trying to pass some data to a separate view controller, the view controller is connected to a navigation controller, i can get to this view controller using

`parentNavigationController!.performSegueWithIdentifier("ExercisePage", sender: self)`

but the data isn't passed along, here is my code?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell2 = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SelectionProperties


    let desVc = uploadDetails1()
desVc.workoutName = cell2.nameLabel!
         desVc.parentNavigationController!.performSegueWithIdentifier("ExercisePage", sender: self)
 }
```

It says it found nil while unwrapping an optional.

`desVc.performSegueWithIdentifier("ExercisePage", sender: self) }`

if i do this,it says theres no segue

Comment: You need to make sure there is a segue with the view controller and your view controller that has the table view in it in your storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: (You don't have to use all if statements...)

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("ExercisePage", sender: indexPath)


    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
        {
            // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.

            if segue.identifier == "ExercisePage"
            {
                guard let indexPath = sender as? NSIndexPath else {
                return } 

                    guard let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? uploadDetails1 else { 
                        return } 
                        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) else { 
                         return } 

                       guard let _ = cell.nameLabel else { 
                          return } 

                            destinationViewController.workoutName = cell.nameLabel!
          }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of this nested `let` statements you should use `guard` statement which came with Swift 2.0

Comment: Ah yeah, you are right, thank you. I changed the answer. Thanks!

Comment: the problem is the prepareforSegue doesn't get called here, because the segue is linked from the navigation controller to the view controller i want to pass detail to, from the current view controller theres no segue, the tableview itself is created programmatically thats why i need to parentNavigationController!.performSegueWithIdentifier("ExercisePage", sender: self) to get it the right page.... very confusing maybe i should just use structs to pass the data, its really easy that way hmmm

Comment: I think it doesn't matter if you build the tableView programmatically. You could link both View Controllers directly. (Maybe I didn't get it...)